# Is it OK to rename server name after configuring the domain controller in it?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and there is domain controller inside of it. Now I need to rename the server name, is it OK rename it directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename a Win2008+ domain controller without major issues.

The preferred method is a three-steps `netdom` dance:

```
netdom computername <CurrentComputerName> /add:<NewComputerName>
netdom computername <CurrentComputerName> /makeprimary:<NewComputerName>
- reboot the DC -
netdom computername <NewComputerName> /remove:<OldComputerName>
```

Using the System Properties GUI is not the recommended method, especially because on older Windows versions it was not up to the task.

Please consider that *both methods* will leave some metadata behind. From [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc816601(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The corresponding nTFRSMember or msDFSR-Member object is not renamed
> automatically, but the reference attributes are correctly set so
> SYSVOL replication is not impacted. The only potential problem with
> not renaming these objects is that if another domain controller is
> created at a later date with the same NetBIOS name of the old domain
> controller, then a conflict can occur as described in KB article
> 316826. After the rename is complete, you can optionally rename the nTFRSMember or msDFSR-Member object as part of cleanup.

These stale metadata can strike back only when adding a new domain controller with the same old name of the renamed one. Otherwise, you will never need to bother with them.